# Leap year Question in Javascript using nested if-else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested-if

In the nested if statement, I have given all the conditions. But some leap years are not being shown as Leap year. For eg: 2000 is coming as a leap year, but year like 2016, 2020 aren't being considered as a leap year. Please Help.

```js
var y = prompt("Enter the year");

if (y % 4 === 0) {
  if (y % 100 === 0) {
    if (y % 400 === 0) {
      alert(y + " is a leap year");
    } else {
      alert(y + " is not a leap year");
    }
  } else {
    alert(y + " is not a leap year");
  }
} else {
  alert(y + " is not a leap year");
}
```

Comment: You could [step through your code to see by yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) why and how the program behaves. Hint: You probably have to use some logical ORs not just logical ANDs. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the year is divisible by 100, you need to check if the year is divisible by 400 too. But what you're missing is, if year is not divisible by 100 but divisible by 4, it is a leap year already. so you need to edit your code like following:

```
if (y % 4 === 0) {
  if (y % 100 === 0) {
    if (y % 400 === 0) {
      alert(y + " is a leap year");
    } else {
      alert(y + " is not a leap year");
    }
  } else {
    //if year is divisible by 4 but not 100, it is a leap year
    alert(y + " is a leap year");
  }
} else {
  alert(y + " is not a leap year");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// program to check leap year
function checkLeapYear(year) {

  //three conditions to find out the leap year
  if ((0 == year % 4) && (0 != year % 100) || (0 == year % 400)) {
      console.log(year + ' is a leap year');
  } else {
      console.log(year + ' is not a leap year');
  }
}

// take input
const year = prompt('Enter a year:');

checkLeapYear(year);
```

Answer (score 0):

The math for date handling is already in JavaScript. It should be possible to check a year using something like "let Dt = DateSerial(year, 2, 29); let isleapyear = Dt.getDate() == 29;

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around "thinking it through" and testing it. The following should work:

```js
for (let y=1995;y<2111;y++)
  console.log(y,
 !(y%4) && !(!(y%100) && (y%400))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution using the if-else statement

```
function isLeap(year) {
   if (year % 4 === 0 || year % 400 === 0){
       console.log("Leap Year");
   }
   else if (year % 100 === 0){
       console.log("Not Leap Year");
   }
   else {
       console.log("Not Leap Year");
   }
}
//and then call the function 
isLeap(2024);
```

Comment: Your `else if` and final `else` do the same thing, therefore you can merge the two blocks together.

Comment: @LeeTaylor 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function isLeap(year) {
  if (year % 400 === 0) {
    return "Leap year."
  } else if (year % 100 === 0) {
    return "Not leap year."
  } else if (year % 4 === 0) {
    return "Leap year."
  } else {
    return "Not leap year."
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a logic error. I not quite sure why you need to check `y%100===0`  and `y%400===0`

I thought `y%4===0` is already enough for check the leap year

but I can tell you 2016 will definitely not passing the `y%100===0` condition.

Since, 2016 divide by 100 will remainder 16